# Meaning of "the lock of someone's personality"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading The Sellout by Paul Beatty. It says:

*There weren’t many memories left. Most, like the suit of armor from which Spanky recited Mark
Antony’s soliloquy in “Shivering Shakespeare” under a barrage of peashooters, **the lock of Alfalfa’s personality**, the top hat and tails Buckwheat wore when he conducted the Club Spanky Big Band and made “hundreds and thousands of dollars” in the “Our Gang Follies of 1938, ...”*

What does "**the lock of Alfalfa’s personality**" mean here?

Comment: As a pure guess, it could refer to the [distinctive lock of hair](https://www.google.com/search?q=alfalfa%20little%20rascals%20hair&tbm=isch&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=0CB8QtI8BKABqFwoTCMjThsit-_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAG&biw=1822&bih=930) that Alfalfa had in the little rascals.

Comment: "[Alfalfa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_"Alfalfa"_Switzer)" is a character from the American "Our Gang" shorts who always had a [cowlick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowlick) or a lock of hair that stood straight up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the references go to the ["Little Rascals" and "Our Gang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Gang) shorts which ran from 1922 until 1944.

Spanky, Alfalfa, and Buckwheat were all recognizable characters based on certain physical attributes.

Alfalfa's trademark was his freckles and an untameable  "cowlick"; hence the 'lock' reference, as in a [lock of hair](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/lock-of-hair).

[image]

He was quite a presumptuous little fellow, with an over-blown opinion of his own appeal to the opposite sex...

Comment: I only answered this because otherwise  it will end up getting closed with an answer that is _nada que ver_.